# How do I collect Tracing information in ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, trace

I'm trying to log every request for my WEB API. 
I followed the instruction in the link below to have tracing information in my output. I wonder what will be a good way to collect those information? For example, I want to store the information into a file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/tracing-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: can you add the code to your post it would helpful?

Comment: Try [Audit.WebApi](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.WebApi/README.md) extension for [Audit.NET](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET). It provides a configurable way to audit Web API applications and more

Answer (score 0):

For my part, I use an ETW for tracing information, it is a very powerful component of Microsoft that provides multiple sink that you can use to store your event, whether in a file or a database .
Documentation  : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/etw/about-event-tracing